# How to best mix HTML developement with server side Python programming?

Tags: python, html

Are there efficient practices for leveraging an HTML IDE with Python (No Framework) instead of the typical outputting of hand coded HTML in python programs that you can't use HTML IDE's with?

I loved the way PHP, JSP, Classic ASP, and .net allow you to include server side code in HTML with the <% tags.  I know some think this is poor form but I personally could stay highly organized with include files while leveraging the WYSIWIG HTML IDE's for presentation polish and experimentation as well as code intelisense.

FYI:  I have gone the IIS ASP route but it just isn't working anymore for anyone I could find online using the latest versions of IIS(8.0).  I'm completely open to other web servers/approaches just so long as its something efficient and would supportable from a reputable remote web hosting provider.

Thank You!

Tim

Comment: I guess i don't understand why posting a question about programming workflow/practices is considered off-topic especially when there are people out there gladly offering answers or direction, and this question is a direct result of other python questions on stack not being answered at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django (https://www.djangoproject.com/) and Flask (http://flask.pocoo.org/) both let you use template languages which let you manipulate and customize HTML pages. However, these processes differ from PHP-style systems in that the code in the HTML page is only related to how you view the data in the page. The bulk of the processing happens in the python code, or the controller (MVC frameworks)

Django's template language: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/
Flask's template language (Jinja2): http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/

Comment: Gilsho thanks for the response, but I was hoping avoid a framework altogether.  I am not a full-time web developer and I've programmed in many languages.  I was hoping to stay very lean here so when I do have a web/side/personal project I could pick up and run very quickly like php.  That said I love the Python language it is just beautiful but I can't find a way integrate it nicely into web development without taking on a framework.

Comment: I'd highly recommend using Flask then. It's a very lightweight "microframework". You can have a simple webserver running with as little as 10 lines of code: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/

Comment: I sincerely appreciate the response and awarding correct answers accordingly.  While I truly love the Python core language and wanted to use it badly, I am a solution arch with history in programming, db design, as well as presentation via HTML/javascript/dom etc...  I can't for the life of me understand why there isn't a easy server side python scripting setup that functions like jsp/php/.net  Templates are great, but combining those with the framework of the day is just too many moving parts for my taste as an part-time web dev.  If anyone knows anything different I will be watching still.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Mako](http://www.makotemplates.org) template library. It is very easy to use, and yet powerful ([usage documentation](http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/usage.html)).

Also, I believe that other popular template libraries can be used outside of a framework as well.